# Issue with dark .PNG files in Unity

Tags: unity, assets, image, png

I made sprite assets in Krita and I exported them as .PNG files. When I import the files into Unity assets, however, they become a lot darker than the original colors. So far, I haven't found the issue, and I was wondering what's going on?

[image: My images appear particularly dark.]

Comment: Which shader are you using.? I think you should use unity -> Texture. it give you perfect result with texture.

Comment: If you want transparent then, Use unity -> Transparent.

Comment: Do you have a gamma or color correction profile embedded in the PNG file? These can cause issues in some tools. I never worked with Krita, but you might want to check the export settings for PNG images.

Comment: Edit -> Project settings -> Player -> Other settings -> Color space: Change it to Linear (or gamma if linear if linear is already selected). Does it fix it?

Comment: Philip how do you check of the PNG file has gamma or color correction?\

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem and this is how I managed to finally resolve it.

In Krita under [Image] > [Properties] I set my profile mode to "sRGB built-in"

[image: kriat image properties]

After that I just re-exported as PNG and imported the new image to Unity, and color was as fine.